# How efficient to retrieve multiple values from multiple tables from mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve 56 values from 8 tables with reference of a user id using php from mysql database. is it possible ?  I want to know how efficient it is? and how to retrieve ?

Comment: Do you know about SQL joins?

Comment: in the 8 tables, are there user id column or its like a chain?

Comment: Yes but how efficient it is..? is it take more time to execute? and which join to use.?

Comment: @Johnbabu19: Of course it takes "more" time—but with appropriately defined indexes, it should be so negligible as not to be a concern.

Comment: It is possible for that you have to use inner join or left outer join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible, If the relationship between all 8 tables is well defined.
How efficient it is? : This is totally depends on the table relationship and how experienced you are in writing efficient queries.

Comment: I have user id in all tables.. my query is very long while using inner join.  and it takes more time to execute. is there any other way to use join with short execution time.?

Comment: You can use , 1 : assign priority to query, 2: Proper indexing, 3: select only required column names 4: Use INNER JOIN On,LEFT JOIN On, RIGHT On in FROM (NOT IN WHERE CLAUSE). Joins in FROM executes more faster than in WHERE